# How to loop in Java and Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have made an alarm clock app however, I am trying to make a homepage where the user can see all the alarms they have set. I want to infinitely run a block of code that updates the homepage of my app, but the methods I have found have not worked (i.e using a timer loop, while, and for loop). Any suggestion would help me a lot, also any critique to the code would help to, Thanks everyone!

I have tried
`Timers`, `Do-While`, `While`, and `For Loops`

The While loop that is in there currently cause an error and the app does not even run.

All the code I need help with is in the While Loop.

I think this is the error

> (I/zygote64: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed classjava.lang.Class: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarms);

    final Button selectAlarm1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectAlarm1);
    final Button selectAlarm2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectAlarm2);
    final Button selectAlarm3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectAlarm2);

    selectAlarm1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    selectAlarm2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    selectAlarm3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    final Button createAlarm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.createAlarm);
    final Button createAlarm2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.createAlarm2);
    final Button createAlarm3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.createAlarm3);

    createAlarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openMainActivity();
                createAlarm2.bringToFront();
            }
        });
    createAlarm2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openMainActivity2();
                createAlarm3.bringToFront();
            }
        });
    createAlarm3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openMain3Activity();
            }
        });

    selectAlarm1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openMainActivity();
            }
        });
        selectAlarm2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openMainActivity2();
            }
        });
        selectAlarm3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openMain3Activity();
            }
        });

    while(true){
            if (Global.intHour1 != 0 && Global.intMinute1 != 0) {
                textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                selectAlarm1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                //fixing minute format
                if (Global.intMinute1 <= 9) {
                    selectAlarm1.setText("Alarm 1 is set for " + 
Global.intHour1 + ":0" + Global.intMinute1);
                } else {
                    selectAlarm1.setText("Alarm 1 is set for " + 
Global.intHour1 + ":" + Global.intMinute1);
                }

            } else if (Global.intHour1 == 0 && Global.intMinute1 == 0) {

                textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
            if (Global.intHour2 != 0 && Global.intMinute2 != 0) {
                selectAlarm2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                //fixing minute format
                if (Global.intMinute2 <= 9) {
                    selectAlarm2.setText("Alarm 1 is set for " + 
Global.intHour2 + ":0" + Global.intMinute2);
                } else {
                    selectAlarm2.setText("Alarm 1 is set for " + 
Global.intHour2 + ":" + Global.intMinute2);
                }
            } else {

            }
            if (Global.intHour3 != 0 && Global.intMinute3 != 0) {
                selectAlarm3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                //fixing minute format
                if (Global.intMinute3 <= 9) {
                    selectAlarm3.setText("Alarm 1 is set for " + 
Global.intHour3 + ":0" + Global.intMinute3);
                } else {
                    selectAlarm3.setText("Alarm 1 is set for " + 
Global.intHour3 + ":" + Global.intMinute3);
                }
            }
            else {

            }
            if (selectAlarm1.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE && 
selectAlarm2.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE && 
selectAlarm3.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
                textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }


    public void openMainActivity () {

        Intent openAlarm = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        startActivity(openAlarm);

    }
    public void openMainActivity2 () {

        Intent openAlarm2 = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);

        startActivity(openAlarm2);

    }
    public void openMain3Activity () {

        Intent openAlarm3 = new Intent(this, Main3Activity.class);

        startActivity(openAlarm3);

    }
    public void makeTextVisible () {


    }

}
```

I want the code to recognize when the intHour1-3 and intMinute1-3 are changed and change the visibility state of a button so that when the user returns to the homepage they can see which alarms are set.

Comment: What is the `textView` and the 3 `selectAlarm` inside the while loop?

Comment: I got it to work on my own, thanks anyway. I found out that every time i switch between activities it restarts it so essential its looping the code.

Comment: Create a well crafted answer and you will gain your first SO reputation increase